# Nested quantifier: Please help me to solve this problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

In Rosen's Discrete Mathematics book(7e) this is the problem no. 12(m) of 1.5th chapter

*There are at least two students in your class who have not chatted with the same person in your class*

where

$C(x,y)$ = $x$ and $y$ have chatted over the internet.

I tried to solve this problem and thought this problem is in the form like "if x has chatted with someone z , then y hasn't chatted with z and if y has chatted with z , then x hasn't chatted with z" and finally came to a solution like this

$\exists x \exists y[(x \ne y ) \land \forall z (( C(x,z) \rightarrow \lnot C(y,z)) \land ((C(y,z) \rightarrow \lnot C(x,z))]$

Is this answer right? If not then what should be the answer.Please explain.

Comment: That seems fine, but wordy.  You could have gotten away with $\exists x,y[(x\neq y)\wedge \forall z(\neg C(x,z)\vee \neg C(y,z))]$, that is, for everyone at most one of $x,y$ chatted with them..  For clarity, we might want to include that $x\neq z$ and $y\neq z$ as well, but that's probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your solution JMoravitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by Contraposition, $C(x,z) \to \neg C(y,z)$ is equivalent to $C(y,z) \to \neg C(x,z)$. So, you are saying the same thing twice there, and it suffices to just use one of them:

$$\exists x \ \exists y [x \neq y \land \forall z (C(x,z) \to C(y,z))]$$

Note that by Implication, this is equivalent to the answer suggested in the Comments:

$$\exists x \ \exists y [x \neq y \land \forall z (\neg C(x,z) \lor C(y,z))]$$

Moreover, if we do a DeMorgan on this, we get another intutive answer, namely that for any person, it is not true that both $x$ and $y$ chatted with that person:

$$\exists x \ \exists y [x \neq y \land \forall z \neg (C(x,z) \land C(y,z))]$$

Finally, using Quantifier Negation, we can pull out the negation, and obtain yet another very reasonable translation: that there isn't anyone that both $x$ and $y$ chatted with:

$$\exists x \ \exists y [x \neq y \land \neg \exists z (C(x,z) \land C(y,z))]$$

Comment: Thanks Bram for your explanation

Comment: @rtawhidur You're welcome!:)